# PdfBox posición de las imagenes

Tags: java, pdfbox2.0

Estoy usando PdfBox 2.0.4 para extraer texto de un área recortada y extraer las imágenes del PDF. El problema está en que cuando configuro el area recortada toma las coordenadas teniendo X = 0 e Y = 0 como la esquina **superior izquierda**, pero cuando extraigo las imágenes e imprimo su ubicación con este [código](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java?view=markup) extraído del SVN oficial de PdfBox toma X = 0 e Y = 0 como la esquina **inferior izquierda**.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class ExtractorDeImagenes extends PDFStreamEngine {

    @Override
    protected void processOperator( Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
        String operation = operator.getName();
        if( "Do".equals(operation) ) {
            COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get( 0 );
            PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject( objectName );
            if( xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)xobject;
                int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
                int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
                //System.out.println("*******************************************************************\n Imagen Encontrada!");
                //System.out.println("Found image [" + objectName.getName() + "]");

                Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
                float imageXScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorX();
                float imageYScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorY();

                // position in user space units. 1 unit = 1/72 inch at 72 dpi
                System.out.println("position in PDF = " + ctmNew.getTranslateX() + ", " + ctmNew.getTranslateY() + " in user space units");
                // raw size in pixels
                System.out.println("raw image size  = " + imageWidth + ", " + imageHeight + " in pixels");
                // displayed size in user space units
                System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in user space units");
                // displayed size in inches at 72 dpi rendering
                imageXScale /= 72;
                imageYScale /= 72;
                System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in inches at 72 dpi rendering");
                // displayed size in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering
                imageXScale *= 25.4;
                imageYScale *= 25.4;
                System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering\n");
            }
            else if(xobject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
                PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject)xobject;
                showForm(form);
            }
        }
        else {
            super.processOperator( operator, operands);
        }
    }

}
```

Por ejemplo, una imagen que está en el top del documento me arroja:

```
position in PDF = 15.0, 460.0 in user space units
raw image size  = 1200, 662 in pixels
displayed size  = 574.0, 317.0 in user space units
displayed size  = 7.9722223, 4.4027777 in inches at 72 dpi rendering
displayed size  = 202.49445, 111.83055 in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering
```

Cuando debería ser:

```
position in PDF = 15.0, 0.0 in user space units
```

Como lo hace cuando quiero definir un sector que está en el top del documento.

No hay una manera de obtener las locaciones de las imágenes de manera ordenada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logré solucionarlo editando el código que cito en la pregunta:

```
@Override
protected void processOperator( Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
    String operation = operator.getName();
    if( "Do".equals(operation) ) {
        COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get( 0 );
        PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject( objectName );
        if( xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
            float altoDeLaPagina = this.getCurrentPage().getMediaBox().getHeight(); // Para obtener la escala Y real dentro del PDF

        PDImageXObject imagenOriginal = (PDImageXObject)xobject; // Obtengo la imagen

        // Obtengo las escalas
        Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();        
        int imageXScale = (int) ctmNew.getScalingFactorX(); // Ya que se necesita este valor como int en 2 funciones, lo casteo ahora una sola vez
        int imageYScale = (int) ctmNew.getScalingFactorY(); // Ya que se necesita este valor como int en 2 funciones, lo casteo ahora una sola vez


        float escalaYReal = (altoDeLaPagina - (ctmNew.getTranslateY() + imageYScale)); // De esta forma obtengo la coordenada Y empezando por la esquina superior izquierda

        System.out.println("La posicion Y empezando de la esquina superior izquierda es: " + escalaYReal);

        } else if(xobject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
            PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject)xobject;
            showForm(form);
        }
    } else {
        super.processOperator( operator, operands);
    }
}
```